# .htaccess directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am not sure how to put this, but I have a php page that pretend to output to a folder but actually it is not. 
so something like this: www.mysite.com/folder/testing.html
here "folder" actually doesn't contain any file called "testing.html", however, "folder" exists on the server with nothing inside.
ok so my dilema is i have taken on this site maintaince, but I am not sure if i need to set my .htaccess, but the link www.mysite.com/folder/testing.html
 doesn't render, it does nothing.
on a different site that i host, a link like that this with the same setup works.
my question is, do i need to check my .htaccess or something on my server?

Comment: Do the other links on the site work or only the homepage? A lot of PHP frameworks route everything through a single `index.php` file in conjunction with an `.htaccess` file which would make your example URL map internally to `www.mysite.com/index.php/folder/testing.html`.

Comment: I think the problem is maybe configuring the virtual host, but i don't know how to do that in cpanel?

Comment: If the configuration was in a vhost configuration file in Apache's conf directory before, you should be able to just copy and paste those settings to the .htaccess file. There are only a few settings that can't be done in .htaccess, which shouldn't affect you -- everything necessary for URL rewriting should be possible with .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if rewrite module is enabled (assuming you're using Apache http server given than you handle rewriting with .htaccess):

```
httpd -M | grep rewrite
```

which should output someething like

```
rewrite_module
```

You can enable the module if missing using the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: yes rewrite module is on, and the .htaccess actually works. I think the problem is maybe configuring the virtual host, but i don't know how to do that in cpanel?

Comment: Can you ensure your virtual host is configured in cpanel to have this directive for your virtualhost:

    AllowOverride All

Before replacing "All" with some more convenient directive type

See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride